# how to setup includes properly with CMake and Bison

Tags: cmake, bison, flex-lexer

I set up our build script to auto-generate sources from Bison/Flex files.
I compile the outputs of Flex/Bison together to a static library and link it to our main executable. Our headers are stored in a separate directory, this directory is known by the library since I used `target_include_directories()`.

The thing that is confusing me is that I get a compile error `Cannot open include file` in the `*.l` and `*.ypp` files. It's definitely the correct one, and also `target_include_directories` points to the same directory each other file in the project uses, and with those, there is no problem at all.

Any ideas?

Edit:

```
find_package(FLEX)
if(NOT FLEX_FOUND)
    message(SEND_ERROR "Flex not found")
endif()
FLEX_TARGET(TOKENIZER Tokenizer.l  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Tokenizer.cpp)

find_package(BISON)
if(NOT BISON_FOUND)
    message(SEND_ERROR "Bison not found")
endif()
BISON_TARGET(PARSER Parser.ypp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MaterialParser.cpp)


ADD_FLEX_BISON_DEPENDENCY(TOKENIZER PARSER)

add_library(flexbison STATIC 
    ${FLEX_MATERIAL_TOKENIZER_OUTPUTS}
    ${BISON_MATERIAL_PARSER_OUTPUTS}
)

target_include_directories(flexbison
    PUBLIC
        "src/header"
)
```

Comment: There is not enough specific info to suggest anything. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: you need to show a minimal version of your lexer and parser source files that reproduce the problem. What is your project's file structure and what are those include files that are not found? Please amend by [edit]ing accordingly.